# What exactly constitutes the 13 attributes for the purpose of not saying them without a minyan?

Tags: tefilla, minyan, selichot, tachanun

The answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18972/1713) mention that the 13 attributes of God are not said in selichos when davening without a minyan. If one is saying selichot without a minyan, exactly what parts constitute the 13 midot which are skipped?

Is it just the attributes themselves *Hashem, Hashem*... *v'nakei*? Does it include some of the paragraphs before or after? If so, which ones? Is the answer the same in other contexts (e.g. Tachanun)?

Comment: See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8911787#8911787 et seq.

Comment: just as a note, I use the Siddur Tefilla Hashalem (Greenwald) which reads (in the viduy before Avinu Malkeinu and tachanun) "hamitpalel beyechidut eino rashai lomar...derech tefilla ubakasha d'ein omrim zeh beyechidut elah b'tzibbur. aval im omer derech kri'ah batorah bnigun uveta'amim mutar"

Comment: @Dan, yes I think someone mentioned that in one of the answers to the linked question. That might be my next question.

Comment: @Daniel thanks! I hadn't checked the question. I see it now.